# Sphinx and user ranking

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sphinx

I have the following mysql table,

```
id, text, rank
```

each time I insert an article I will put ranking as 1 like so,

```
1, blah blah, 1
```

then if more than one person read this text the rank will be increased by one.

So what I need is to do a sphinx search for the below 2 texts based on the keywords and on the ranking.

```
1, blah blah, 2
2, blah blah blah, 6
```

so if the user search for keyword "blah" then the result should be

```
2, blah blah blah, 6 //first as the ranking is higher
1, blah blah, 2
```

I'm not sure how to do that, do I need do the search for the keywords in sphinx and then sort the result of the document based on the rank? which is not good.

Or, is there anything in sphinx available for this kind of problem?

I've been reading about the ranking on the sphinx documentation but it looks like it's related to the text itself and the weight of the words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Sphinx, you can set the 'rank' as an integer attribute in the index.

**Attributes**, are stored directly in the index, and can be used for sorting, filtering etc.

So can then sort your results by the attribute (rather than by the computed full-text weight)

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#attributes

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sorting-modes

Comment: So if I understood correctly, I need to update the ranking field in the DB and then the search should be sorted based on that field? do I need to re-index after the sql update btw ?

Comment: You need to rebuild the index, whenever the source data changes, or the SQL is changed. Ie indexer builds a static index. To apply changes the index has be built again.

Comment: ok so is it possible to set the attr in the index and then instead of update the DB I will update the value of the attr in the index?

Comment: Well there is http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-updateatttributes :) So can update the attribte as go along

Comment: right, and I saw that also http://php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.updateattributes.php